# boolean function that contains "bab"

Tags: java, recursion

How could I have a recursive boolean method that will check if it contains bab. I have this but I I'd like to do it recursively.

```
public static boolean hasBAB(String str) {
      if (str.length() < 3) return false;
      if (str.substring(0,3).equals("bab"))
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If the `String` starts with `"bab"` or if it contains it? Why would you need recursion to see if it starts with it? You only need to check in one place, the beginning of the `String`.

Comment: If it starts with `"bab"`, it doesn't make sense to do it recursively.

Comment: if it contains it anywhere

Comment: That's what you need: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: @AnupamSaini It's not,as it's not recursive. See comments below my answer.

Comment: @JohannesH. Fair enough up-voted your answer. But he better have a valid reason for recursive solution :)

Comment: Agreed ;) Most likely it's a purely academic reason, aka "we're learning recursion right now".

Comment: I wish it was academic instead of teaching myself

Comment: oh, that's a valid reason, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion should be thought of as two parts.

1) A base case. This is trivial case that can easly be determined.
What you have so far is a good start to a base case.
1) Is the string less then 3? Then return false.
2) Does the string start with "bab" then return true.

2) A recursive case.
This splits the problem up into a tinier problems, and if you split them up enough hopefully you have a base case.

@Logiraptro has a good example of a simple recursion.

```
public static boolean hasBAB(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 3) return false;
  if (str.substring(0,3).equals("bab"))
    return true;
  else
    return hasBAB(str.substring(1));
}
```

This uses your base cases, and as a recursive case checks the string from index one on. This reduces our string only by one charter, but is enough to solve the problem.

This means we end up with a stack level of the length of the string.

Can we do better?  A little, by breaking the problem in half we only need a stack level of ln(n) where n is the length of string. This is not a big deal for most lengths, but if you were searching a string with a length of one million it maybe significant. With the first version our stack would be about a 1,000,000 deep! But with this binary version we only need to go about 14 levels deep.

This comes at a cost though, our solution because more involved.

Our base cases
1) If the string is less then the length of the search string, return false.
2) If the string is length of the search string, if they are equal return true, else return false.
3) If the string appears over the mid point of the string return true.

If none of these are true,we break the string into two parts and recursively check over that string.

Here is an example of that algorithm, you can replace "bab" with any string you like, although it hasn't been fully tested for that I'm pretty sure it will be okay.

```
public static boolean hasBAB(String str) {
      String searchString = "bab";

      // Base cases
      if (str.length() < searchString.length()) 
          return false;

      if (str.length() == searchString.length())
      {
          if (str.equals(searchString))
          {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }

      int halfWay = str.length()/2;

      // Now check for the search string over the "break"
      for (int i = 0; i < searchString.length(); i++)
      {
          int startIndex = halfWay - 1 - i;
          int endIndex = startIndex + 3;
          if (startIndex >= 0)
          {
              String substring = str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
              if (substring.equals(searchString))
              {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

     // Recursive Cases 
     //  We did find the search string over the break,so break the string into two equal(ish) pieces and check those 
     if(hasBAB(str.substring(0,halfWay -1)))
         return true;

     if(hasBAB(str.substring(halfWay, str.length())))
         return true;

     return false;
}
```

Comment: What a great explanation..I read every word and I actually learned something today. I wish I could give you 10 likes. This will be a the best answer for sure!

Comment: Thanks - glad you liked it.  You should take a look at a binary search.  Same basic search, but we can cut the list in half each time because it's sorted so it's way better. Same with comparing a bubble sort and a quick sort.  Same basic idea. It's neat stuff.

Comment: Not sure what advantage binary search should bring here - it'S only great for sorted content where you actually only need to process one half. That's not the case here... Compared to the trivial approach, you'Re faster if the match is in the last half, but slower if it'S in the first one. SO just switched. It'S still O(n).

Comment: @JohannesH., yeah - they are both O(N) in terms of comparisons, but Logiraptor's solution is O(N) in terms of stack count too. The binary search is O(ln(n)) for stack count. So try running the two on a string of around 30,000. The basic approach gives a stack overflow.  The binary approach does not, at least on my computer. Also, I think Ris wanted this answer for educational purposes (because you would never actually do this recursively) so I thought a more in depth answer would be helpful to him showing both solutions. Especially if next he wanted to look at a binary search or quick sort.

Comment: Got your point. I have to admit, I didn't think of stack count, I usually don't have any recursive task that might fill it.

Comment: @JohannesH. - Yeah, tail recursion is basically a loop which is of course the best way to handle this. Also, the binary search was more fun to do :)

Comment: Forget my previous comment about tail recursion, it wasn't that well thought-through - it would't make too much sense here, as, as you already said, it's basically a loop then ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
public static boolean hasBAB(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 3) return false;
  if (str.substring(0,3).equals("bab"))
    return true;
  else
    return hasBAB(str.substring(1));
}
```

But you should really use `String.contains`

Comment: As this HAS to be a recursive function, this answer is acceptable. It's clearly not a general purpose solution, as it's a mess performance wise - String is immutable, and LOTS fo string instances are created here. If a recursive function should be deployed for whatever reason in non-academic environments, think about creating a `StringBuffer` or any `char[]` or `List<Char>` and work on that.

Comment: This can probably be simplified to: `return str.length() >= 3 && (str.substring(0, 3).equals("bab") || hasBAB(str.substring(1));` :)

Comment: @JoshM Not sure about operator precedence right now. DOes `&&` bind higher than `||` ? I think so - and in that case, you'll need paranthesis I guess.

Comment: @JoshM DId you just edit them in, or did they exist all along? Anyway, looks ok now ;)

Answer (score 4):

No need for recursion ;) You're looking for [`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
public static boolena hasBAB (String str) {
    if (String.length() < 3) return false;
    else return str.contains("bab");
}
```

Comment: but I want a recursion :(

Comment: He wants a recursive function. I think it's more for his conceptual purposes than practical.

Comment: Accepted. See my comment on that at the other answer however.