# Recursive isSubtring method java

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods

I have the following question:

Write a recursive static method isSubstring with the following signature -

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1,String s2)
```

gets two strings - s1, s2 and returns true if s2 is a **substring** of s1.

**the method should be recursive without using iterations at all. also any other method you write (if you write).**

**the correct answer does not change the method type signature/annotation (not even by overloading)**.

**you can only use the following methods in your solution:**

public char charAt(int i)

public int length()

public String substring(int i)

---

that's what I have so far, I know it doesn't work IE isSubstring("hello","ho") will return true. any idea what could be done?

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s2.length() == 0)
        return true;
    if ((s1.length() == 0) || (s1.length() < s2.length()))
        return false;
    if (s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0))
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1), s2);
    else
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use another recursive method to verify the rest of `s2` matches after you find the first character. Another interesting test case is `isSubstring("hello","lo")` which should return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it.

It uses an auxiliary method. When you see the first match, it will call the auxiliary method and verify if the substring matches from that point. If it doesn't, it tries the same with the next match.

```
public static boolean isSubstring(final String s1, final String s2) {
    if (s2.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((s1.length() == 0) || (s1.length() < s2.length())) {
        return false;
    }

    if (s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0)) {
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1), s2);
    }

    if (!isSubstringAux(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1))) {
        return isSubstring(s1.substring(1), s2);
    }

    return true;
}

public static boolean isSubstringAux(final String s1, final String s2) {
    if (s2.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0)) {
        return isSubstringAux(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost good but you have to somehow remember that you made a replacement. I propose the following solution (using a helper function with a different prototype, which fits the requirements of the problem) :

```
public static boolean sub(final String s1, final String s2, final boolean hasReplaced) {
    if (s2.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((s1.length() == 0) || (s1.length() < s2.length())) {
        return false;
    }
    if (s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0)) {
        if (hasReplaced) {
            return false;
        }
        return sub(s1.substring(1), s2, hasReplaced);
    }
    return sub(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1), true);
}

public static boolean isSubstring(final String s1, final String s2) {
    return sub(s1, s2, false);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that you just coded some sort of `startsWith`. I think that this will only return `true` if `s1` **starts** with `s2`!

Comment: Actually `isSubstring("I say hello", "hello"));` returns `true`. There must still be a bug though because `isSubstring("hello", "lo")` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2) {
    return s2.length() == 0
            || ( s1.length() >= s2.length()
                && ( matchStartOfString( s1, s2 )
                    || isSubstring( s1.substring(1), s2 )
                    )
            );
}

private static boolean matchStartOfString( final String s1, final String s2 )
{
    return s2.length() == 0
            || (    s1.length() >= s2.length()
                &&  s1.charAt( 0 ) == s2.charAt( 0 )
                &&  matchStartOfString( s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1) )
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2){
    if (s2.length == 0) return true;
    if (s1.length < s2.length) return false;
    if (s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0)) 
        return isPrefixString(s1.substring(1, s2.length), s2.substring(1, s2.length)) 
            || isSubstring(s1.substring(1, s1.length), s2);
    return isSubstring(s1.substring(1, s1.length), s2);
}

private static boolean isPrefixString(String s1, String s2){
    if (s2.length == 0) return true;
    if (s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0)) return false;
    return isPrefixString(s1.substring(1, s1.length), s2.substring(1, s2.length));
}
```

Basic algorithm:

isSubstring function:

Base case 1: If s2 is empty (either because it's empty or because it's been exhausted) then return vacuous truth (every string contains the empty string).

Base case 2: If s1 is shorter than s2, then s1 can't possibly contain s2, so return tautologic false.

Recursive case 1: If s1 contains s2, then some substring of s1 starts with the same letter as s2 starts with.  Therefore, if s1 does not start with the same letter as s2, find some other point in the string to use as the start point.  By "some other", this algorithm just iterates linearly through the string.

Recursive case 2: If s1 and s2 start with the same string, test whether s2 is a prefix string of s1 (i.e. if s1 starts with s2) recursively.  If s2 is not a prefix string of s1, then try another start point.  Otherwise, s2 is a prefix of s1 and hence s1 contains s2.

Note that the code has recursive cases 1 and 2 backwards from how I've written it here.

isPrefixString function:

Base case 1: If s2 is empty, then return (vacuous) truth.

Base case 2: If s1 and s2 do not start with the same letter, then s2 cannot possibly be a prefix of s1, so return false.

Recursive case: If s1 and s2 start with the same character, check if the next character is the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion should be thought of as two parts.

1) A base case. This is trivial case that can easily be determined.
What you have so far is a good start to a base case.
1) Is the string less then 3? Then return false.
2) Does the string start with "bab" then return true.

2) A recursive case.
This splits the problem up into a tinier problems, and if you split them up enough hopefully you have a base case.

Here is a good example of a simple recursion.

```
public static boolean substringRec(String str, String str2) {
      if (str.length() < str2.length()) return false;
      if (str.length() == str2.length())
      {
          if (equals(str, str2))
            return true;
          return false;
      }
      else
        return substringRec(str.substring(1), str2);    
}

public static boolean equals(String str1, String str2)
{
    if (str1.charAt(0) == str2.charAt(0))
    {
        if (str1.length() == 1)
            return true;

        return equals(str1.substring(1), str2.substring(1));                
    }
    return false;
}
```

This uses simple base cases and as a recursive case checks the string from index one on. This reduces our string only by one charter, but is enough to solve the problem.I had to implement a .equals since apparently you can't use that, you can do that in a similar way.

This means we end up with a stack level of the length of the string.

Can we do better?  A little, by breaking the problem in half we only need a stack level of ln(n) where n is the length of string. This is not a big deal for most lengths, but if you were searching a string with a length of one million it maybe significant. With the first version our stack would be about a 1,000,000 deep! But with this binary version we only need to go about 14 levels deep.

This comes at a cost though, our solution because more involved and will break some of the rules you have on your assignment, but I think it's interesting to think about.

Our base cases
1) If the string is less then the length of the search string, return false.
2) If the string is length of the search string, if they are equal return true, else return false.
3) If the string appears over the mid point of the string return true.

If none of these are true,we break the string into two parts and recursively check over that string.

Here is an example of that algorithm, although it hasn't been fully tested for that I'm pretty sure it will be okay.

```
public static boolean substringRec2(String str, String searchString) {       

      // Base cases
      if (str.length() < searchString.length()) 
          return false;

      if (str.length() == searchString.length())
      {
          if (str.equals(searchString))
          {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }

      int halfWay = str.length()/2;

      // Now check for the search string over the "break"
      for (int i = 0; i < searchString.length(); i++)
      {
          int startIndex = halfWay - 1 - i;
          int endIndex = startIndex + 3;
          if (startIndex >= 0)
          {
              String substring = str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
              if (substring.equals(searchString))
              {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

     // Recursive Cases 
     //  We did find the search string over the break,so break the string into two equal(ish) pieces and check those 
     if(substringRec2(str.substring(0,halfWay -1), searchString))
         return true;

     if(substringRec2(str.substring(halfWay, str.length()), searchString))
         return true;

     return false;
}
```

Note - taken from one of my previous answers and modified - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594554/3096507

Comment: OP Said: *the method should be recursive without using iterations at all*.

Comment: Also `you can only use the following methods in your solution:` does not include the `equals()` method.

Comment: @MT0 - Thanks updated my first example to remove equals(), or rather give a recursive definition using only the allowed functions. I know the second example doesn't fit within the restraints but though it is interesting to someone learning about recursion so I included it.